# purrr:pmap not passing values from a list

Tags: r, purrr, pmap

Calling a function from pmap is throwing an error as arguments are not being passed on their own

Tried creating lists of the parameters but this too has resulted in an error

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

periods <- c(10,11,12)
redemption <- rep(100,3)
firstcallDate <- c("2014-01-01","2015-01-01","2016-01-01")
testdf <- data.frame(redemption, periods, firstcallDate)
testdf$firstcallDate <- as.Date(testdf$firstcallDate)
testdf$CallSch <- NA

CallScheduleGen <- function (redemption,periods,firstcallDate, ...) {
  Price <- rep(as.double(redemption),periods)
  Date <- seq(firstcallDate, by = "1 month", length = periods)
  callSch <- data.frame(Price, Date)
  return(callSch)   
}

testdf$CallSch <- pmap_dfr(testdf,CallScheduleGen)
```

I am expecting a dataframe to be created in each of the cells in the testdf dataframe.  Pmap appears to pass input arguments to the functions as a list, rather than element-wise.

Can anyone suggest an approach as I need this to be vectorized rather than creating a loop?

Comment: Try using `pmap` instead of `pmap_dfr`

Comment: thanks @Humpelstielzchen this helped with the output.   


So that others dont encounter this issue, pmap strips Date format:
[link](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358)

To get round this I changed the function:
`Date <- seq(as.Date(firstcallDate,origin = "1970-01-01"), by = "1 month", length = periods)`